# Alignment Problems, HTML/CSS/Rails, Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with alignment using HTML and CSS on Rails with Bootstrap. If its an easy question, excuse me as I'm new at this.

Anyway I'm trying to align content with a secondary navbar; trying to make the content align with the dimensions of the navbar, and a sidebar to stay fixed. Though, when I put the sidebar content (everything in `div class='span4'` in `show.html.erb`) in the application layout file, then the content aligns itself properly horizontally but vertically there is a big space where the sidebar is.

The way I have it now, I get this:
[image]

But I don't understand why? I really thought I'd aligned everything properly. I need the burndown chart to be under the navbar, and the project leader/description and edit stuff to be under the title.

`show.html.erb`:

```
<script src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">
     <p><strong>Project Leader:</strong> <%= @project.user.email %></p>
     <p><%= @project.description %></p>

     <% if current_user == @project.user %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(@project), :class => 'btn' %> 
     <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="span8">
      <% if @project.milestones.count != 0 %>
         <div class="chart" id='chart'></div>
          <%= render_chart @chart, 'chart' %>
      <% end %>
      <div class="span8">
        <%= render template: 'project_users/index' %>
      </div> 
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

`application.html.erb` in layouts:

```
<% if request.original_url =~ /\/projects\/[0-9]+/ %>
  <div class="toprow">
   <div class="span4">
     <p><h1><%= @project.name %></h1></p>
   </div>
  <div class="span8">
   <div class="secondary-nav">
     <%= link_to "Overview", "/projects/#{@project.id}", class: 'btn btn-default'  %>
     <%= link_to "Management", "/projects/#{@project.id}/milestones", class: 'btn btn-default'  %>
     <%= link_to "Documents", "/projects/#{@project.id}/etherpads", class: 'btn btn-default'  %>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

And Bootstrap overrides:

```
.toprow {
margin-top:30px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
}
```

Sorry about the bad coding style here; I know everything should be in their own partials and layout files, but the people I am helping out have decided to do it this way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should also add the row class to the toprow?

```
<div class="row toprow">
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things I noticed:

First, assuming you're using Bootstrap 3 you shouldn't be using the `span` class. Per the Bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) you should use something like `col-xs-4`. Also, you're declaring this:

```
<div class="span8">
        <%= render template: 'project_users/index' %>
</div>
```

within another column. You need to first declare another row within the column before you can do that.

Should be like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-8>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-8>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Lastly, make sure your rows are residing within a `container` or the grid won't work. This container can be a wrapper in your application layout.